# Log rank - Cox regression

Tags: survival

I have question , If I want to investigate the effects of Factors on the overall survival and progression free survival which the best way to do that by using the log rank or cox regression ( univariable or multivariate)  ? and why ?

our study is retrospective data for patient with cancer they treated with chemo+ radio therapy
Total number of Patient is 51
only 3 died ( overall survival )
and 16 relapse or recurrence ( progression free survival)

I want to see the effects of this factor on our survival :

- Age ( continues )

-Symptoms ( Yes or no ) :
Headache
Nasal obstruction
Epistaxis
Hear loss

Overall stage ( categorical 4 category )
EBV Baseline ( if the virus Positive or negative at diagnoses )
Total dose of radiation ( continues )
EBV post RT( if the virus Positive or negative after treatment  )
Duration of Treatment on days  ( continues ) " if the patient who have more days on treatment have higher or lower risk to have the event "

Thanks ,

Comment: The logrank test is a special case of Cox so no need to mention it here.  But the big problem is that with 3 events you can't do any statistical analysis other than to show the Kaplan-Meier curve.  It is not possible to study how patient characteristics relate to the outcome when you have fewer than 20+ events.

Comment: What about 16 event ( relapse ) ? can we yes the cox in this number ? I tried some variables and it's work !

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  With 19 overall events you have enough data to look for an association with **one pre-specified** patient characteristic.  Without heavy unsupervised learning (data reduction) nothing you learn will replicate in another dataset of similar patients.